# Is the complement of an affine open in an abelian variety ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $U$ be an affine open subscheme of an abelian variety $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Is $A-U$ an **ample** divisor?

If $\dim A =1$ this is true. 
If $\dim A = 2$, the complement is a divisor $D_1+\ldots + D_n$. If all of these are elliptic curves, then the complement is not affine (as it will contain the translate of one of these elliptic curves). So, wlog $D_1$ is not an elliptic curve. But then $D_1$ is ample (by Nakai-Moishezon). And this implies that $D_1 +\ldots +D_n$ is also ample.

I couldn't figure it out for abelian threefolds.

Comment: This is actually the way projectivity of abelian varieties is typically proven, cf. Mumford's *Abelian varieties*, p. 59 (p. 62 in the first edition). See also Theorem 10.9 of [Bhatt's notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/abelian_varieties.pdf).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Welcome new contributor.  Yes, that is true.  Let $k$ be any field, let $A$ be an Abelian variety over $k$, and let $U\subset A$ be a dense open affine.  Denote by $D\subset A$ the complementary divisor with its induced reduced structure.  Denote the invertible sheaf of this divisor by $\mathcal{L}:=\mathcal{O}_A(D).$  Denote by $s$ the global section of $\mathcal{L}$ whose zero locus equals $D.$

Ampleness can be proved after faithfully flat base change over $\text{Spec}\ k$, thus assume that $k$ is algebraically closed.  By Lemma II.5.14 of Hartshorne, for every $g\in \mathcal{O}_A(U)$, there exists an integer $n_0$ and a section $\widetilde{g}\in \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n_0}(A)$ such that $\widetilde{g}|_U$ equals $g\cdot s^{n_0}|_U$.  Notice that for every integer $r\geq 0$, also $s^r\widetilde{g}|_U$ equals $g\cdot s^{n_0+r}|_U$.  Since the $k$-algebra $\mathcal{O}_A(U)$ is finitely generated, there exists an integer $n_0>0$ such that the image of $(s|_U)^{-n}\cdot \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}(A) \to \mathcal{O}_A(U)$ generates $\mathcal{O}_A(U)$ as a $k$-algebra for every $n\geq n_0$.  In particular, the base locus $B_n$ of the complete linear system of $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ is disjoint from $U$, and the induced morphism to projective space, $$\phi_n:A\setminus B_n \to \mathbb{P}^{d_n}_k,$$ restricts as a locally closed immersion on $U$.

The set $A(k)_{\text{tor}}$ of torsion $k$-points $a$ of $A$ is dense.  Thus, denoting by $$\tau_a:A\to A$$ the morphism of translation by $a$, for every $k$-point $p$ of $A$, the set $\{\tau_a(p)| a\in A(k)_{\text{tor}} \}$ is dense in $A$.  In particular, not all of these points can lie in the proper, Zariski closed subset $D$.  Thus, there exists an integer $m>0$ and an $m$-torsion point $a$ such that $\tau_a^*D$ does not contain $p$.  In other words, the point $p$ is contained in the open affine subset $\tau_a^{-1}(U)$.

Since $a$ is $m$-torsion, $\tau_a^*\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ for every positive integer $n$ that is divisible by $m$.  For such $n$, also the base locus $B_n$ is disjoint from $\tau_a^{-1}(U)$, and $\phi_n$ restricts to a locally closed immersion on $\tau_a^{-1}(U)$.

The set of translates $\tau_a^{-1}(U)$ for $a\in A(k)_{\text{tor}}$ is an open affine covering of $A$.  Since $A$ is quasi-compact, there exist finitely many torsion translates of $U$ that cover $A$.  For $m>1$ equal to the least common multiple of the orders of those finitely many torsion points, for every positive integer $n$ that is divisible by $m$, the base locus $B_n$ is disjoint from each of these open translates in this open covering.  Thus, the base locus $B_n$ is empty.  Moreover, the $k$-morphism $\phi_n$ restricts as a locally closed immersion on each of these open translates.

If $\phi_n$ had a positive dimensional fiber, that fiber would intersect one of these open translates in a positive dimensional subvariety, and that would contradict that $\phi_n$ is an immersion on that open translate.  Thus, every fiber of $\phi_n$ is finite.  Since $\phi_n$ is a morphism between proper $k$-schemes that has finite fibers, the morphism $\phi_n$ is a finite morphism.  Since the pullback of an ample invertible sheaf by a finite morphism is ample, the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n} \cong \phi_n^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is ample on $A$.  Finally, since $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$ is ample, also $\mathcal{L}$ is ample.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation.